# Error thrown in flutter app on navigator '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

When moving to the login screen by clicking a button on the home screen this error was thrown. I couldn't understand why this occurred. As in the error message shown in the emulator I visited https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors but couldn't figure out much in there either.

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    //this provide total height and width of screen
    return Background(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "WELCOME TO BATCHMATE",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.07),
            SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/icons/chat.svg',
              height: size.height * 0.45,
            ),
            FlatedButton(
              text: 'LOGIN',
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return LoginScreen();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.01),
            FlatedButton(
              text: 'SIGN UP',
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
              textColor: Colors.black87,
              press: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> This was the thrown error:

```
E/flutter ( 7445): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3022 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.
E/flutter ( 7445): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
E/flutter ( 7445): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
E/flutter ( 7445): #2      _RouteEntry.handlePush.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3022:18)
E/flutter ( 7445): #3      TickerFuture.whenCompleteOrCancel.thunk (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:407:15)
E/flutter ( 7445): #4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)
E/flutter ( 7445): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter ( 7445): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7445): #6      TickerFuture.whenCompleteOrCancel.thunk (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart)
E/flutter ( 7445): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 1):

I handle routes this way, maybe it can help you fix your issue.

Its a little complicated at first but once you understand how it works, it saves a lot of time.

on each of your screens you add a static constant with whichever name you want, i usually call them screenId.

```
static const String screenId = 'screen_name';
```

create a file called routeGenerator where you are going to put all the routes that your app has.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main.dart';

import 'screens/chat_screen.dart';
import 'screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'screens/email_registration_screen.dart';
import 'screens/welcome_screen.dart';

class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch (settings.name) {
      case WelcomeScreen.screenId:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => WelcomeScreen(),
        );
      case EmailRegistrationScreen.screenId:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => EmailRegistrationScreen(),
        );
      case LoginScreen.screenId:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => LoginScreen(),
        );
      case ChatScreen.screenId:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => ChatScreen(),
        );
      default:
        return _errorRoute();
    }
  }

  static Route<dynamic> _errorRoute() {
    return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('404'),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
                },
                child: Text('Regresar'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

then on your main.dart you add a gobal key and some parameters to your MaterialApp();

```
import 'route_generator.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: WelcomeScreen.screenId,
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    );
  }
}
```

And to navigate to the screen you can add the static constant of the screen to navigate to that particular screen.

```
LongButton(
      text: 'Regístrate',
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      callback: () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, EmailRegistrationScreen.screenId);
      },
    ),
```